# Firebase Analytics custom event with AnalyticsEventItem

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

In a Flutter application, I'm trying to define my own view_cart event with custom parameters. So I decided to copy some of the code pieces from firebase_analytics library in order to send data successfully.

Here is the filterOutNulls function from firebase_analytics library:

```
  Map<String, Object> filterOutNulls(Map<String, Object?> parameters) {
    final Map<String, Object> filtered = <String, Object>{};
    parameters.forEach((String key, Object? value) {
      if (value != null) {
        filtered[key] = value;
      }
    });
    return filtered;
  }
```

Here is the _marshalItems function from firebase_analytics library.

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? _marshalItems(List<AnalyticsEventItem>? items) {
    if (items == null) return null;

    return items.map((AnalyticsEventItem item) => item.asMap()).toList();
  }
```

This is my logEvent function:

```
      await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(
        name: 'view_cart',
        parameters: filterOutNulls(<String, Object?>{
          "user_id": userId,
          "currency": convertSymbol(dvz),
          "value": totalPrice,
          "items": _marshalItems(list),
        }),
      );
// list variable is type of List<AnalyticsEventItem>
```

Finally, output of terminal:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_analytics/src/firebase_analytics.dart': Failed assertion: line 115 pos 9: 'value is String || value is num': 'string' OR 'number' must be set as the value of the parameter: items
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      FirebaseAnalytics.logEvent.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase_analytics/src/firebase_analytics.dart:115:9)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617:13)
#4      FirebaseAnalytics.logEvent (package:firebase_analytics/src/firebase_analytics.dart:113:17)
```

What I don't understand that the variables inside logEvent function is exact copy of logViewCart function. Even though they are same, logEvent function throws error but logViewCart does not.

Can anyone explain me where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Use This Method**

```
 static void customLogEvent({
        required final String key,
        required final Map<String, dynamic> parameters,
      }) async {
        await FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(
          name: key,
          parameters: parameters,
        );
      }
```

---

**you Can add List to the Value of the Map**

```
List<Student> students = [
    Student(name: "John", rollno: "12", age: "26", marks: [23, 45, 35]),
    Student(name: "Krishna", rollno: "12", age: "26", marks: [23, 45, 35]),
    Student(name: "Rahul", rollno: "12", age: "26", marks: [23, 45, 35])
];
     
var studentsmap = students.map((e){
        return {
                "name": e.name, 
                "rollno": e.rollno, 
                "age": e.age, 
                "marks": e.marks
            };
    }).toList();
print(studentsmap);
```

**Output**

```
[
 {name: John, rollno: 12, age: 26, marks: [23, 45, 35]}, 
 {name: Krishna, rollno: 12, age: 26, marks: [23, 45, 35]}, 
 {name: Rahul, rollno: 12, age: 26, marks: [23, 45, 35]}
]
```

Comment: you should use  Map<String, dynamic> parameters,

Comment: Yes I know parameters must be Map<String,Object?> but if I want to put List<Object> variable inside the Map, it throws error. My main question is, how to add List<Object> to items key inside parameters that makes Google Analytics allow as proper key-value.

Comment: Set the value type to dynamic

Comment: I think you can create the list and store it as a string, for example join the list and convert to string

Comment: `items.map((AnalyticsEventItem item) => item.asMap()).toList();` this line does the exact thing you suggested. But still it throws error. 

The output of the code is below. 

`[{discount: 30.0, item_brand: 452, item_category: 3025, item_id: 1383118, item_name: White Coat, price: 90.93}]`

Comment: convert list to String

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue in FlutterFire Github ([check this out](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11159)) and I saw that what I wanted to do is not supported by Google. It is **not possible** to assign a List of Objects to items parameter in custom logEvent.

So I have to stick with pre-defined logging functions that Firebsase Analytics allows.